# Execute jsp file from Jquery Pop-up

Tags: jquery, jsp

```
function duplicateCountry() {
    var username = $('#Country_name').val();
    if (username == "" || username.length < 4) {
        $('#Country_name').css('border', '3px #CCC solid');
        return false;
    }

    alert(username);
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/jsp/admin/master/Checkcountry.jsp",
        data: 'username= ' + username,
        cache: false,
        success: function (response) {
            if (response == 2) {
                alert("Success");
            }
        },
        error: function () {
            document.getElementById("Error").innerHTML = "*duplicate value"
            alert("fail");
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

duplicateCountry function is called by onclick event of a button. but the problem is response(function) always returns false although it perfectly executes Checkcountry.jsp

and this one is mine Checkcountry.jsp

```
<% 
DBCountry op = new DBCountry();
String edit=request.getParameter("edit").trim();
String hide = request.getParameter("hide").trim();
int i = op.updateCountry(edit,hide);
response.setStatus(i);

%>
```

Please help me out. I am stuck here........
it always return false. and page got stuck

Comment: In what file is the jquery located?

Comment: Is `op.updateCountry(edit,hide)` returning HTTP response codes? If it is not 200, then it will go the error callback.
You could open the JSP directly in your browser, if it is HTTP/200 or not.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing }); at the end.